# JetBrains WebStorm not detecting installed Linux distributions for Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux, node.js, webstorm

I am trying to debug nodejs code using the debugging features available in WebStorm on an Ubuntu or Debian Linux distribution installed on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I followed the directions listed on the websites below, but my WebStorm installation refuses to detect the Linux distributions I have installed on my system, and I've already set a default distro using wslconfig.exe.

[image: List of installed distors from wslconfig.exe]

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912772/how-to-use-wsl-as-default-terminal-in-webstorm-or-any-other-jetbrains-products
- https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/06/webstorm-2018-2-eap-182-3208/

Additionally, I don't seem to have a way to tell WebStorm manually that I have Linux distributions installed on my system.

See screenshot below:
[image: Screenshot of WebStorm WSL distribution nodejs selection screen]

**Questions:**

1. Is there a configuration setting I'm missing for WebStorm in
   relation to its detection of WSL distribution detection?
2. How can I get WebStorm to detect my Linux distributions?

**Please note:** This is for break debugging capabilities using WebStorm and not just terminal use. I was able to to get the terminal running with no issues, but need the debugging features available in WebStorm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may become an issue if you are running versions of WSL that are not installed using the Windows store. JetBrains has an official fix, but if you want a different method to install Linux distributions the default way you can run the following code in PowerShell:

```
$REGKEY="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
$REGITEM = "DoNotConnectToWindowsUpdateInternetLocations"

function Set-RegistryItem {
    param (
        # Registry key to set
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $RegistryKey,

        # Registry item to set
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $RegistryItem,

        # Value to Set
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Value,

        # Value type to Set
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]
        $Type
    )

    if ($(Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::$RegistryKey -Name $RegistryItem)) {
        New-ItemProperty -Path Registry::$RegistryKey -Name $RegistryItem -PropertyType $Type -Value $Value -Confirm -Force
    }
}

Set-RegistryItem `
    -RegistryKey "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate" `
    -RegistryItem DoNotConnectToWindowsUpdateInternetLocations `
    -Value 0 `
    -Type DWord

Set-RegistryItem `
    -RegistryKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsStore `
    -RegistryItem AutoDownload `
    -Value 4 `
    -Type DWord

Set-RegistryItem `
    -RegistryKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\WindowsStore `
    -RegistryItem RemoveWindowsStore `
    -Value 0 `
    -Type DWord
```

This will temporarily enable the windows store and allow you to install programs you might need (Linux distros). If your group policy prevents the execution of PowerShell, you are out of luck.

Additionally, the windows store will be disabled when you restart your computer if disabled by group policy.

Once a Linux distribution is installed in the default way via the Windows store, JetBrians picks it up almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

you can try adding your distributions to `~\.WebStorm2019.1\config\options\wsl.distributions.xml` manually. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32424#focus=streamItem-27-3332472.0-0, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/configuring-remote-interpreters-using-wsl.html#custom_wsl for more info.
Note that you need to specify full path to executables. Short names are working with default installation roots only.